# Activity is not getting saved

Tags: android

My activity is using checkboxes.I have used startActivityForResult() from another activity and navigates towards this one, now from this activity I want to return the intent but before that I want to save the state of checkbox for that I have used onRestoreInstanceState and onSavedInstanceState but activity state is not getting saved.Each time the state of savedInstanceState is shown as null.Is it because that i am calling finish() and after that onDestroy is called and i am not able to save my data.Here's my code for this activity:-

```
    package 

    import android.app.Activity;


    import android.content.Intent;


import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.CheckBox;

    public class FilterRequestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private CheckBox checkBox1;
        private CheckBox checkBox2;
        private CheckBox checkBox3;
        private CheckBox checkBox4;
        private CheckBox checkBox5;
        private Button button;
        private StringBuffer url=new StringBuffer();
        private StringBuffer equalUrl=new StringBuffer();
        private StringBuffer mainUrl=new StringBuffer();
        private StringBuffer requestUrl=new StringBuffer();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(savedInstanceState==null)
            Log.e("Filter_onCreate","null");
        else
            Log.e("Filte_onCreate","notNull");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_filter_request);
        checkBox1=findViewById(R.id.one);
        checkBox2=findViewById(R.id.two);
        checkBox3=findViewById(R.id.three);
        checkBox4=findViewById(R.id.four);
        checkBox5=findViewById(R.id.five);
        button=findViewById(R.id.button);
        //if(savedInstanceState!=null)

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                returnIntent.putExtra("result", (CharSequence) requestUrl);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });


    }

    public void onCheckBoxClicked(View view) {

           }


    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Log.e("FilterActivity","onSaveInstanceState is called");
        outState.putBoolean("box1",checkBox1.isChecked());
        outState.putBoolean("box2",checkBox2.isChecked());
        outState.putBoolean("box3",checkBox3.isChecked());
        outState.putBoolean("box4",checkBox4.isChecked());
        outState.putBoolean("box5",checkBox5.isChecked());

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.e("FilterActivity","onRestoreInstanceState is called");
        checkBox1.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("box1"));
        checkBox2.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("box2"));
        checkBox3.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("box3"));
        checkBox4.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("box4"));
        checkBox5.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("box5"));
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    }
}
```

onCheckBoxClicked is defined in my layout

Answer (score 0):

The method `onSaveInstanceState` is used by the activity to save its state in case for example of an Activity's recreation or device rotation. When the activity is destroyed, you can't access anymore to that data. I think the only way you have to save the value of your checkboxes is to use SharedPreferences, it's quite easy and straightforward to implement